# How can i redirect dropdown with submit button

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I want to redirect url when select one option and click on go button how can i redirect on the button.My go button redirect on the same url.

```
    <?php
global $wpdb;
echo "hello";
// $sql="SELECT  path FROM `grillM_blogs` WHERE blog_id";
  $sql="SELECT * FROM grillM_blogs";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
//print_r($results); 
?>
<form id="search_mini_form">
<select class="mypopup" id="websites">
        <option>select location</option>
<?php
foreach($results as $res) {
    $newstring = str_replace("/"," ",$res->path);
    $newstring=ucwords($newstring);
     ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $res->path;?>"><?php echo $newstring;?></option>
         <?php } ?> 
        </select>
       <button class="go">Go</button>
<a href='' class='close'>Skip</a>

</div>
</div>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".go").change(function(){
            var go_to_url = $("#website").find("option:selected").val();
            window.location = go_to_url 
           // alert("hello");       
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you should use .click event instead of .change event.

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion would be to simply make the onchange event change the location href without needing the button click, but if you want to keep the "go" button, then you could it into an `<a>` link and then in the js have an onchange function for the select list that changes the href of the link. Note that I am using Bootstrap to style the link into a button but it can be done in other ways too. I also cut down the code you had and lost the php just for this example to show the dynamic changing of the "go" links href (to google or to SO depending on the selection). Try changing the selection and then mouseover the go button to see the new href.

```js
$(function() 
 {  
  $('#websites').on('change',function(){
  var loc=$(this).val();
  $('.go').attr('href',loc);
  })
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" /> 
    <title>Select Demo</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 <select class="mypopup" id="websites">
        <option>select location</option>
        <option value="https://www.google.com.au/?gws_rd=ssl">Google</option>
        <option value="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow</option>
        </select>
  
      <a href="#" class="button go btn btn-success btn-xs">Go</a>
  <a href='' class='close'>Skip</a>

 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```